# Crosswalk (cross-walk) as a verb

Tags: etymology, verbs, terminology

I have seen the word crosswalk (cross-walk) used as a transitive verb in the sense of align, compare, connect, link, relate, etc. ("Crosswalk your labor categories to the tasks in the statement of work.") ("We will crosswalk your estimated costs to each of the contract tasks.") I cannot find this usage in *any* dictionary, but I have seen it in some legal decisions and government documents, and I have seen some scholarly articles that mention or describe various kinds of "crosswalk analysis."

When did this usage begin? In what field or profession?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I haven't heard "crosswalk" in this usage. But I have heard "socialize" (as in "It'll take a while for other areas to accept this idea. We need to socialize it first.") But I have seen its decline with the corresponding rise of "social media."

Comment: Looks like a "misuse" to me, where the normal verb would be ***crosslink***

Comment: Yep, never heard it (in the US).

Comment: ("Cross-reference" may be what was intended.)

Comment: This appears to be military jargon then coopted into management-speak. I can't be certain it started with the US military, though, despite the earliest example I could find being from a 1997 military journal.

Comment: I came across the term in a U.S. government request for proposals that was issued by a civilian agency and that became an issue in litigation. The issue was whether there is a distinction between crosswalk analysis and what is called "price realism" analysis. The court ruled that there is a difference in terms of the depth of the analysis, crosswalk being less detailed.

Comment: My research has found that published usage by the U.S. government dates back to the mid-1960s, pertaining to budgetary matters. Usage was rare, and I could find no official explanation or source of origin. Usage began to increase in 2000 in various contexts and appears to have surged after 2010. There is still no official definition or explanation. Crosswalk has been used as a noun, adjective, and transitive verb.

Comment: "Crosswalk" is not a common term in the UK in any event: I think of it as an American term.

Comment: @VEdwards it's amazing to me how obfuscating government lingo can be when English can so easily be clear.

Comment: @VEdwards, if there is a court opinion dealing with the matter, doesn't that amount to there being an 'official definition or explanation'? When a word is used in legal contexts, it means whatever the courts say it means.

Comment: This term was in use in budgeting in the U. S. government in the 1980s to refer to explaining the differences between two sets of numbers. The noun was more common than the verb form.

Comment: UD carries the sense (the noun cross-walk).

Comment: @TrevorD I am an American who has recently entered his late 50s, and I've never heard this word before.  I would be unable to understand what it meant unless it could be inferred from the context, which may be the case for the second sentence, but not quite for the first.

Answer (score 1):

Crosswalk as a verb, distinct from the markings at intersections, is indeed established in US military, government, and IT contexts. It is not, however, widespread in other contexts. It simply refers to comparing two different documents (or policies or objects; easiest to think of it as involving documents) that cover the same or similar subjects. The goal is to assess how they compare and contrast, what is consistent and inconsistent. A very formal crosswalk would generate a third document, a table or a redlined version of the source document, to show how they line up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is used in terms of higher education. When students come in as transfers, they need to "crosswalk" their credits from the previous institution into credits at the new institution. I am now seeing it in K12 literature where an idea from one area (like research evidence) is being "cross-walked" into a new area (for example into teachers' practice).

Comment: "in terms of" or "in the context of"? And couldn't this be the same erroneous use of crosslink as mentioned in the comments?

Comment: It's different to "crosslink" because in the example of college credits it means to transfer credits from one course to count for another course, not simply to compare credits between courses. You could use "carry across" or "transfer" in the same context.

Comment: The observation that such use of the word can also be found in this context, doesn't quite answer the OP's question of where it started.

Comment: What is Transference of Learning

[IGI Global](https://www.igi-global.com › dictionary › transference-o...) defines 
**transference of learning** as 'the ability for students to apply knowledge and skills from one context to multiple [or at least other] contexts'. That's how I learned the term was used.  Terminology gets somewhat confusing hereabouts.

Answer (score 0):

Crosswalk has been a verb used in health services IT and modeling since at least the 1980s. The typical IT crosswalk is a map between coding systems, for example, a list showing what diagnoses in the International Classification of Diseases, 9th Edition, Clinical Modification correspond to each diagnosis in the National Electronic Injury Surveillance System or the Workers' Compensation ANSI Z-16.2 diagnosis coding system. Once you develop the crosswalk map, you apply it to a dataset to crosswalk (merge) data coded in another coding system onto the dataset.